# Сортировка по чекбоксам php

Tags: php, checkbox

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность сортировки по выделенным чекбоксам?
Т.Е. после отправки чекбокса, отсортировать данные, например по дате.
Скажем так, мне перед удалением выбранных чекбоксов, нужна сортировка с наименьшей датой.
Очень грубо говоря это бы выглядело так.
Select min[$date] from checkbox
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Вообще чек приходит или да или не приходит, для такого проще сделать скрытое поле с аналогичным названием и потом на бэке сравнивать что пришло и соответственно строит выборки

Comment: А так в целом по вопросу я не могу сказать ничего конкретно вашей ситуации я не вижу ни кода ни что у вас уже есть или то как вы пытались решить проблему

Comment: имеется в виду что чекбокс уже пришел, и вот он готов к удалению из БД, но перед этим я хочу сделать сортировку по дате, например для инсерта в БД перед удалением.

Comment: Я вот реально сейчас вас не понял. Вы хотите сделать выборку перед тем как удалите после вставки?

Comment: Это равносильно "Я хочу выкинуть пустое ведро но прежде чем выкинуть хочу его налить и посмотреть чем я его налил"... Поставьте вопрос корректней или же всё таки покажите что вы делаете

Comment: Вы хотите удалить выбранные записи но вначале отсортировать?

Comment: @Walfter :> Ну как тут успехи?

Comment: @Manitikyl не могу понять что хочет автор=) Толи ведра выкинуть толи вначале по порядку их расставить

Comment: @Walfter Я после строчки `Select min[$date] from checkbox` даже париться не стал. Автор просто что-то там себе надумал, но не хочет говорить что, а нам пытается абстрактно описать, а нам сиди и догадывайся что и как у него там. Так хороший шашлык не сделаешь.

Comment: @Manitikyl я всё же надеялся что автор даст больше подробностей

Comment: Прошу прощения, отходил.
Вот у меня есть переменная $date_GET['date']
я забил дату в эту переменную, нажимаю поиск, выходят строки с чекбоксами в диапазоне этой даты, выделяю чекбоксы которые хочу удалить
теперь перед удалением этой информации, я хочу создать функцию, где будет высчитывать минимальную дату из выбранных чекбоксов, и вставвлять ее в таблицу.
извините если опять криво объяснил, не знаю как по другому.
Если и тут не понятно, то можете не отвечать, вопрос закрою.

Comment: "Я хочу выкинуть пустое ведро но прежде чем выкинуть хочу его налить и посмотреть чем я его налил", хах почти так
Только ведро не пустое, ведро залитое, и скажем там есть еще и картошка.
И я хочу найти самую маленькую из этих картошек, а остальное выкинуть.

Comment: Попробую еще раз сформулировать вопрос.
есть поиск по диапазону дат для вывода информации.
на странице забиваешь даты, дата с - дата по
нажимаешь поиск выходит информация
далее эту информацию(строки) можно выделить по чекбоксам, после выделения чекбоксов, можно удалить одну или несколько записей.
в строке у меня есть столбец с датой события
и я хочу перед удалением записей по чекбоксу, выбрать строку у которой дата события самая минимальная и вставить ее в таблицу.

Comment: @БогданЛисовский может теперь и немного ясней, вы хотите вначале сделать выборку показать её пользователю, далее идёт выделение записей посредством чеков а перед удалением вы хотите записать какую дату?

Comment: @Walfter так точно!
я предполагаю это должно выглядеть как то так.
Я передаю в чекбокс еще и переменную дату события
Далее дописать перед удалением что то вроде
Insert into tbl(date) value (select * from $checkbox where date = (select min(date) from $checkbox) опять же это очень грубо говоря
Такое вообще возможно?